# Why properties of the JSON object come at null at Angular request on the Spring Java side?

Tags: java, json, spring, angular

I am sending the same Post request from the Angular Application and the Chrome poster.

From the Poster I specify the following:
URL:  http://localhost:8080/rentapp/policy

Header:
content-type    application/json

Content: body
{
"title": "NoSmoking", 
"description":"NoSmoking" 
}

In the Spring Controller I have the following code:

```
@PostMapping
// @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
public ResponseEntity<?> create(@Valid AttributeDTO policy, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    logger.debug("CreatePolicy=" + policy);
```

AttributeDTO is defined as:

```
@Data
public class AttributeDTO {
private String title;
private String description;
}
```

**I see that after the Poster request AttributeDTO is populated.**
In Angular I Have the following method

```
public addPolicyWithObservable(policy: Policy): Observable<Policy> {
const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
console.log("addPolicyWithObservable policy=" + policy + " url=" + this.url + " http=" + this.http);
const ret: Observable<Policy> = this.http.post(this.url, policy, options)
  .map(this.extractData)
  .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
console.log ("addPolicyWithObservable ret=" + ret);
return ret;
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
const body = res.json();
return body.data || {};
}

private handleErrorObservable(error: Response | any) {
console.error(error.message || error);
return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
}
```

In the Policy model:

```
export class Policy {
public id: number;
public title: string;
public description: string;

toString(): string {
return this.title + ': ' + this.description;
}
}
```

I see that after this request the properties of AttributeDTO (title and description ) are null on the Java side.  That is despite the fact that the request comes to the Java side and on the Angular side the logging before sending is correct, i.e the title and description are properly populated:

addPolicyWithObservable **policy=NoSmoking: NoSmoking** url=/api/policy http=[object Object]

createpolicy.service.ts:20 addPolicyWithObservable ret=[object Object]

Answer (score 0):

That may be because you have no function to convert incoming JSON to actual objects, or you're not telling Spring that you expect it to consume JSON.

```js
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
// @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
public ResponseEntity<?> create(@Valid AttributeDTO policy, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    logger.debug("CreatePolicy=" + policy);
```

I'm not too sure if you gonna need this `dependancy`, but just in case.

```js
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.8</version>
</dependency>
```

```js
public addPolicyWithObservable(policy: Policy): Observable<Policy> {
const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
console.log("addPolicyWithObservable policy=" + policy + " url=" + this.url + " http=" + this.http);
return this.http.post(this.url, policy, options)
  .map((res) => res.json() as Policy)
  .catch((err) => Observable.throw(console.error(err)));
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't have worked, but I'm not too sure how the Chrome Post works. You could however try something like Postman to do the call and see if that works too

Comment: Adding @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) did not help.  In my view the problem is on the Angular side, how to get what was send?

Comment: @AlexNarinsky It maybe the way you wrote the angular method, I have added a modified version of the `addPolicyWithObservable` method to the post above, see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

try using the `@RequestBody` annotation for the `AttributeDTO`.

```
public ResponseEntity<?> create(
    @RequestBody AttributeDTO policy,
    BindingResult bindingResult)
{
    logger.debug("CreatePolicy=" + policy);
    ...
```